# Is the determinant a scalar?

Tags: definition, determinant

**Note**: by *scalar*, I am referring to the notion which is very commonly mentioned in tensor algebra (scalar = 0-order tensor); I do not have a definition, so please share it if you have one. Roughly speaking, I sometimes read that a 0-tensor, i.e. a scalar, defines 1 amplitude and 0 directions.

In the general case, a scalar field, e.g. a temperature field $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ depends on a change of basis: for some invertible $P$, $T(x)\neq T(Px)$.

On the contrary, the determinant, e.g. $\det: M_n(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$ is invariant by change of basis: $\det(M)=\det(PMP^{-1})$. Does it mean the determinant is not a *scalar*?

Comment: Could you define exactly what you mean by a "scalar"?

Comment: @Ravi: "something that transforms like a scalar", obviously :P  [ In all seriousness, probably something like this was intended: http://www.physicspages.com/2015/10/29/tensors-transform-like-tensors/ ]

Comment: I see. Also shouldn't det be a function from $\mathbb R^3\times\mathbb R^3\times\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R$ instead of just two copies?

Comment: @Ravi: thank you, edited.

Comment: @EricStucky Unfortunately the link only gives the definition of a 2d-order tensor. It implies that a scalar field is invariant by rotations, but it is not clear if this is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the determinant is a [*pseudoscalar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscalar): not a differential form of degree zero, but of top degree.